# sh script unable to get executed in New Empty Docker Container

Tags: bash, shell, docker

I have a .sh script below when get executed in New Empty Docker container gives below error. I am unable to find where exactly is the issue.

My aim is to connect to install Jenkins in Empty container using sh script.

jenkins.sh script

```
# Install Java:
yum -y install java
# Verify java install:
java -version
# Download Jenkins from the Red Hat repo:
yum install wget
wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat/jenkins.repo
# Import the verification key using the package manager RPM:
rpm --import https://jenkins-ci.org/redhat/jenkins-ci.org.key
# Install Jenkins by running:
yum -y install jenkins
# Input Y
#Add Jenkins to system boot
chkconfig jenkins on
# Start Jenkins as a service:
service jenkins start
# TODO: Add IP address of server:
netstat -tnlp | grep 8080
# Open browser to http://138.68.1.138:8080
```

error message--

```
[root@b07136d674f7 tmp]# ./jenkins.sh
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.solarvps.com
 * extras: centos.mirror.constant.com
 * updates: mirror.net.cen.ct.gov
 available.java
Error: Nothing to do
./jenkins.sh: line 4: java: command not found
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.solarvps.com
 * extras: centos.mirror.constant.com
 * updates: mirror.net.cen.ct.gov
 available.wget
Error: Nothing to do
--2016-12-21 06:29:17--  http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat/jenkins.repo%0D
Resolving pkg.jenkins-ci.org... 52.202.51.185
Connecting to pkg.jenkins-ci.org|52.202.51.185|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2016-12-21 06:29:17 ERROR 404: Not Found.

curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL
: import read failed(2).i.org/redhat/jenkins-ci.org.key
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.solarvps.com
 * extras: centos.mirror.constant.com
 * updates: mirror.net.cen.ct.gov
 available.jenkins
Error: Nothing to do
chkconfig version 1.3.49.5 - Copyright (C) 1997-2000 Red Hat, Inc.
This may be freely redistributed under the terms of the GNU Public License.

usage:   chkconfig [--list] [--type <type>] [name]
         chkconfig --add <name>
         chkconfig --del <name>
         chkconfig --override <name>
         chkconfig [--level <levels>] [--type <type>] <name> <on|off|reset|resetpriorities>
./jenkins.sh: line 16: service: command not found
```

Comment: Why don't you use the official jenkins image? Would you mind adding the Dockerfile? Which part of the error message don't you understand? `Illegal characters found in URL`and `service: command not found` are your first problems to solve.

Comment: @rdupz We need a script which can get executed all time.Image and Docker-file will not work in our product. When I run this commands individually in container everything works perfect. But when i execute via script the above is the error.

Comment: start the service from the path where its installed e.g.: `/etc/init.d/jenkins start`